# Groovy mixin combined with Gradle DefaultTask results in runtime error

Tags: groovy, gradle, mixins

To explain my problem in the simplest way, I'll first show you a Groovy script that does work and then add some Gradle sauce which breaks it.

The working script:

```
class MyMixin {
    String myname = 'max'
}

@Mixin(MyMixin)
class MyClass {}

MyClass c = new MyClass()
println 'hello ' + c.myname
```

This prints out "hello max" as expected. Now let's replace that `MyClass` with a Gradle task class. For this we extend [DefaultTask](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) and use the `@TaskAction` annotation.

```
@Mixin(MyMixin)
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    void sayHello() {
        println 'hello ' + myname
    }
}
```

If we now install this Gradle task and execute it, we get the following runtime error:

```
Execution failed for task ':myproject:mytask'.
> MyTask.getMyname()Ljava/lang/String;
```

What's funny is that this only happens with methods returning something. `void` methods execute just fine.

So the question is simple: **how can I get my mixin to cooperate with my Gradle task?** (FYI: it doesn't seem to be related to inheritance; I checked that, but didn't include it in the sample script to keep it simple. I have also tested with a runtime mixin instead of compile-time: the result is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on the Gradle forum and according to the Gradle developers it is an incompatibility between Groovy's `@Mixin` and Gradle's own meta-programming facilities. They suggest to use Gradle's extra properties and/or extension objects instead.

For reference: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/groovy_mixin_combined_with_gradle_defaulttask_results_in_runtime_error